# Using number and message localization seperatly in vue i18n

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-i18n

I want to use Vue I18n for the currency, date and message localization for my web app. The users can seperatly configure the language and the used currency format. For Example: A german user wants a english localized website, but the currency format should be EUR and 'de-DE'.

Is it possible to build this with Vue I18n? Like a seperate locale configuration for currency?

I could pass the BCP 47 language code in the template, but then i have to load the current configurated language code for each component. I'd like to solve this more dynamically.

`<p>{{ $n(price, 'currency', currentLanguageCode) }}</p>`

```
const numberFormats = {
    'en-US': {
        currency: {
            style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'
        }
    },
    'de-DE': {
        currency: {
            style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'
        }
    },
    'de-CH': {
        currency: {
            style: 'currency', currency: 'CHF'
        }
    }
}

const i18n = new VueI18n({
    numberFormats,
    messages: {
        en: {
            test: 'test message'
        },
        de: {
            test: 'Testnachricht'
        }
    },
    locale: 'de',
    fallbackLocale: 'de'
})
```